# how can static variables be directly used in lambda's body even the invoking beyond the scope of the static variables

Tags: c++, lambda

i'm getting confused when reading the capture rule of local static variables for lambda, see below codes:

```
std::function<bool(int)> returnLambda()
{
    static int s_b = 1;

    return [](int a){return a+s_b ;} ;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    i = returnLambda()(2);

    return i;
}
```

in the returnLambda function, when lambda expression is envaluated, one function object is constructed and returned.Then there is one copy at the invoking place, and operator() is invoked at the invoking place, so does the local static variable. here the question is, why the local static variable inside the returnLambda function can still alive even outside the returnLambda function?
generally you can not refer to one local static variables outsie it's sope.

Comment: Because that's what *closure* means; you *close* over the variables (and thus capture them).

Comment: seems there is no such statement in the c++11 standard, and seems there is also no static variable capture scheme description in the c++11 standard.

Comment: If your overarching question is "what part of the standard specifies this specific behaviour?", then the answer is "I don't know"!  If it's simply "how can it work?" then the answer is simply "because that's how it's implemented".  I could hypothesise on how that's achieved, but does it really matter?  (Is it any more or less magical then any other advanced C++ feature?)

Comment: Lambdas are implemented as function objects. They implicitly create a class and object with the extra data necessary to implement any captures.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: This lambda doesn't capture anything.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for lambdas state that you can't use any captured entity beyond the lifetime of said entity.

The lifetime of an object with static lifetime is until the end of `main()` (or call to `exit()`).  So there's no problem using it after returning the lambda.  Only usage in the destructors of other objects with static lifetime (e.g. globals) could be a problem.

In fact, this variable isn't even captured by the lambda.  No need, just like there would be no need to capture a global variable.  It works because identifier lookup within the lambda finds an object with static lifetime in an enclosing scope, so it gets used.  Because the variable does not have automatic storage duration, the rule for implicit capture isn't triggered.

This is the rule, from 5.1.2:

> A lambda-expression with an associated *capture-default* that does not explicitly capture `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration (this excludes any *id-expression* that has been found to refer to an *init-capture*'s associated non-static data member), is said to *implicitly capture* the entity (i.e., `this` or a variable) if the *compound-statement*:
>
> - odr-uses (3.2) the entity, or
> - names the entity in a potentially-evaluated expression (3.2) where the enclosing full-expression depends
>     on a generic lambda parameter declared within the reaching scope of the *lambda-expression*.

The whole reason for the capture machinery is so that the lambda can locate variables it uses, if those variables have a time-varying location.  Static variables (and globals, and static class members, and functions, and whatever else isn't an automatic local variable or a non-static data member of `this`) don't move around, so sticking their location in the lambda object isn't necessary.

In short: You absolutely can continue using static locals outside their scope.  Many standard library functions work this way, for example `asctime`.  Scope determines whether the name is recognized; for objects with static or dynamic lifetime, scope has no effect on lifetime.

Comment: Hi, but this "s_b" is just declared inside one function, can anybody refer to it outside that function? no "s_b was not declared in this scope" come out when compile?

Comment: @LiuNick: Using references or pointers.  This is a dangling reference: `int& f1() { int x; return x; }`.  This is perfectly fine: `int& f2() { static int y; return y; }`

Comment: per your statement " Scope determines whether the name is recognized". s_b is defined inside retureLambda, so it's scope is inside returnLambda, then why s_b is still be recognized outside returLambda?                                                        "i = returnLambda()(2);"

Comment: @LiuNick: The name `s_b` is not recognized outside of that lexical scope.  Your program doesn't use the name outside of its scope.  During a call of the lambda, you are running code which is inside the lexical scope.  It's a lot like a public accessor for a private member variable.  `private` doesn't protect against code outside the class learning the value of the private variable... just against *direct* usage.  Same here.  The name being out of scope does not prevent the object from being used in `main()`... it just can't be used *directly* by its name.  It can be used indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

lambda lives inside returnLambda, is this what you're asking? ><

Comment: thanks for the great drawing, firstly.  yes, lambda lives inside returnLambda, but what stored in the std::function<bool(int)> is one copy of that lambda. the copy will use static variable, but the static variable ony declared inside returnLambda function. I think at whereever we can not refer the local "s_b" excpt inside the function.

Comment: @LiuNick I don't think std::function will make a **copy** on that lambda. actually, it would have a pointer **points to** the lambda structure

Comment: @owensss: It has to copy it.  What could it make a pointer to?  A temporary object that is being destroyed?